# Creating a tiff stack from individual tiffs in python

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I am creating tiff stacks of different sizes based on the example found here: 
http://www.bioimgtutorials.com/2016/08/03/creating-a-z-stack-in-python/

A sample of the tif files can be downloaded here:
[nucleus](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12CuVWWUs9horuNIcbKnsOYrYJnWLb9pM)

I have a folder with 5 tiff files inside.
I want to stack them to be able to open them in imageJ so that they look like this:

[image]

And this works with the following code:

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
import os

dir = 'C:/Users/Mich/Desktop/tiff stack/'

listfiles =[]


for img_files in os.listdir(dir):
    if img_files.endswith(".tif") :
        listfiles.append(img_files)



first_image = io.imread(dir+listfiles[0])

io.imshow(first_image)

first_image.shape

stack = np.zeros((5,first_image.shape[0],first_image.shape[1]),np.uint8)



for n in range(0,5):
    stack[n,:,:]= io.imread(dir+listfiles[n])

path_results = 'C:/Users/Mich/Desktop/'
io.imsave(path_results+'Stack.tif' ,stack)
```

The problem comes when I just want to stack the 4 first ones or the 3 first ones.

Example with 4 tiff images:

```
   stack=np.zeros((4,first_image.shape[0],first_image.shape[1]),np.uint8)

   for n in range(0,4):
       stack[n,:,:]= io.imread(dir+listfiles[n])
```

Then I obtain this kind of result:
[image]

and while trying to stack the 3 first images of the folder, they get combined!

```
   stack=np.zeros((3,first_image.shape[0],first_image.shape[1]),np.uint8)

   for n in range(0,3):
       stack[n,:,:]= io.imread(dir+listfiles[n])
```

[image]

Where am I wrong in the code, so that it dosent just add the individual tiff in a multidimensional stack of the sizes 3, 4 or 5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the color space of the image data (`photometric='minisblack'`), otherwise the tifffile plugin will guess it from the shape of the input array.

This is a shorter version using tifffile directly:

```
import glob
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffWriter('Stack.tif') as stack:
    for filename in glob.glob('nucleus/*.tif'):
        stack.save(
            tifffile.imread(filename), 
            photometric='minisblack', 
            contiguous=True
        )
```